# creating a new chained RDB in kdb

Tags: kdb

Am I able to create a new chained RDB that subscribes to current RDB for one table only?? or I can only subscribe to TP or chained TP only?

I am thinking to create a chained RDB for calculations, but cannot afford to have another same table in chained RDB. The calculation is based on trades, it has to go through all records within like 5-10 minutes for the same symbol. Not sure what is the best way to do it.

If it is to subscribe to RDB, do I need to load u.q in RDB to make it subscrible?

Comment: Can you edit the format of your question- you have a code block for normal text. Edits have to be more than 6 characters for external editors. Thanks

Comment: ok just edited.

Answer (score 3):

I would subscribe to the TP/chainedTP rather than trying to convert your RDB into a publisher itself. You can subscribe to an individual table from the TP/chainedTP and it should be well able to handle the additional subscription (if it isn't then your system has bigger problems).

Your new process can have a timer and use `.z.ts` to run periodic calculations and perhaps wipe the trade data after each use.